# Tomcat 7, Raspberry Pi Spring-boot, Java 1.8, maven application, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, jhipster project

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, raspberry-pi

I get error when I deploy my web-app on raspberry using Tomcat7.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: box/ApplicationWebXml : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class box.ApplicationWebXml)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2961)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.loadClass(Introspection.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2072)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2046)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2039)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1304)
...
```

This error does not occurred while I was starting application with ./mvnw.

The java and javac version are the same:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_65
```

This is fragment of my pom.xml specifying java version:

```
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
     <liquibase-hibernate4.version>3.5</liquibase-hibernate4.version>
     <liquibase-slf4j.version>2.0.0</liquibase-slf4j.version>
     <liquibase.version>3.4.2</liquibase.version>
     <logstash-logback-encoder.version>4.7</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
     <mapstruct.version>1.0.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
     <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
     <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
     <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
     <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

Of course I can access index.html but after that there is no resource to get. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked which java version Tomcat is using? It seems Tomcat doesn't use java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

This means that your tomcat instance is running on a JVM lower than version 8.

You need to check what version of the JVM tomcat is using (could do it quickly using):

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

If the java versions do not match, update the JAVA_HOME variable in `/etc/default/tomcat7` to point to your java 8 folder.